# How i use AND operator in sparql querys in java

Tags: sparql

I am learning how to create SPARQL queries in java. Can anyone explain to me how i can use AND operator in 2 or more queries?

For example:

```
String queryString ="SELECT * WHERE {" + "?A <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/capital> ?B" +
AND   //how can use AND???
"?A rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/big_city>" + "}";
```

Comment: You question got nothing to do with Java or SQL - your problem is SPARQL. And formatting... And: what did you tried? Do you get an exception? Which exception?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `AND` in SPARQL.  Triples patterns are simply placed on after another.  There are several synatx sort cuts.

```
SELECT * WHERE { 
  ?A <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/capital> ?B .
  ?B rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/big_city> .
}
```